# AWS AppSync - GraphQL query timeout when running from AppSync Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

**Intro**

I'm following the intro tutorial found [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/react-native) to create a Todo List app using Amplify + AppSync + GraphQL. All was working fine until I started testing out queries in the AppSync console on my GraphQL API.

**Problem**

When running my queries on the GraphQL API, the queries timeout randomly. Sometimes they work fine, and sometimes they take a long time and eventually throw an error. **See the image below for a full example with the error.**

**Questions**

- Has anyone ever had this *DynamoDB:ApiCallTimeoutException* error message before using AWS AppSync with GraphQL?
- Is there any way to avoid getting a timeout error?

I'm new to everything AWS, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's an internal AWS temporary issue.

You can find it on your personal dashboard
https://phd.aws.amazon.com/phd/home#/event-log

"[7:08 AM PDT] Between 4:41 AM and 6:36 AM PDT, we experienced increased API latencies in the US-EAST-1 Region. The issue has been resolved and the service is operating normally.

[7:46 AM PDT] We are investigating increased API latencies in the US-EAST-1 Region.

[8:24 AM PDT] We can confirm increased API latencies in the US-EAST-1 Region and continue to work towards resolution.

[9:55 AM PDT] Between 4:41 AM and 9:00 AM PDT, we experienced increased API latencies and timeouts in the US-EAST-1 Region. The issue has been resolved and the service is operating normally."